# Help to renew membership using the API

Tags: civimember, api, php, renewals

I would like to programatically renew memberships when a transaction has been completed in Woocommerce.
I want my members to have a more consistent experience and since I do a lot through the woocommerce store already, I wanted to do renewals and new memberships.

I need some confirmation to see if I'm doing this correctly though -
For a new membership, I think it is straight forward to simply do:

--confirm no membership entries exist already for this contact_id

$result = civicrm_api3('Membership', 'get', [
  'sequential' => 1,
  'contact_id' => 15947,
]);

--Create a new membership entry

$result = civicrm_api3('Membership', 'create', [
  'membership_type_id' => "Registered Participant",
  'contact_id' => 15947,
  'start_date' => 20200513,
  'end_date' => 20210513,
  'source' => "Payment",
]);

But for a renewal, I don't want to keep adding additional lines of membership entries so I am thinking same above except if an entry is found, issue a create with the ID and it should renew it correctly?

--confirm no membership entries exist already for this contact_id

$result = civicrm_api3('Membership', 'get', [
  'sequential' => 1,
  'contact_id' => 15947,
]);

-- Entry found so renew

$result = civicrm_api3('Membership', 'create', [
  'membership_type_id' => "Registered Participant",
  'contact_id' => 15947,
  'start_date' => 20200513,
  'end_date' => 20210513,
  'source' => "Payment",
  'status_id' => "Current",
  'id' => 8746,
]);

So the only difference between a new membership and a renewal is the 'id' and 'status_id' ?

Answer (score 2):

So this was my solution.  Using Wordpress triggers, its fired off whenever an order is submitted and successfully paid.  If it contains the product to create new/or renew then.  I hope it helps someone.  I still need to add some error traps, otherwise should work fine for my setup.

```
 # Product ID for the registered participant is noted below
 #error_log("Line items: $item\n");
 if ($item["product_id"] == 33706) {
     $result = civicrm_api3('Membership', 'get', [ 'sequential' => 1, 'contact_id' => $contactid, ]);
     if ($result["count"] == 0) {
         #create new membership entry
         #start date/end date will be today to 1 year out
         $start_date = date("Ymd");
         $end_date = date('Ymd', strtotime($start_date. ' + 1 year'));
         $result = civicrm_api3('Membership', 'create', [ 'membership_type_id' => "Registered Participant", 'contact_id' => $contactid, 'start_date' => $start_date, 'end_date' => $end_date, 'source' => $item["order_id"], ]);
     } else {
         #renew membership
         $current = $result[values][0];
         $current_start_date = $current['start_date'];
         $current_end_date = $current['end_date'];
         $membership_id = $result['id'];
         if ($current_end_date < date()) {
             $new_start_date = date("Ymd");
         } else {
             $new_start_date = $current_end_date;
         }
         $new_end_date = date('Ymd', strtotime($new_start_date. ' + 1 year'));

         $result = civicrm_api3('Membership', 'create', [ 'membership_type_id' => "Registered Participant", 'contact_id' => $contactid, 'start_date' => $new_start_date, 'end_date' => $new_end_date, 'source' => $item["order_id"], 'status_id' => "Current", 'id' => $membership_id, ]);
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a feature called "auto-memberships" in this extension:
https://github.com/adixon/ca.civicrm.contributionrecur

It might almost do what you want (it'll update existing memberships, won't create new ones, but you could add that).

There's a little record that connects a payment with a membership, which is nice if you add it, so that you can more easily identify payments that haven't yet been connected.

Comment: Not really what I'm after.  Similar but looking to use in a Wordpress plugin since it will be fired by the Woocommerce triggers.  If no one tells me otherwise, I will go ahead and write it up as I explain above and see if it works.  Thanks.